# Gparted no deja redimensionar

Tags: ubuntu

Instale Ubuntu 18.04 en todo mi disco duro sin crear ninguna partición, ahora tengo la necesidad de crear una partición, estoy usando Gparted pero no me permite redimensionar, ni crear una tabla de particiones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Como puedes observar tu disco duro tiene un símbolo de una llave, eso quiere decir que no puedes redimensiónalo por que la partición esta activa.

Si quieres redimensionar tu disco duro raíz tienes que ejecutar el **Live USB**, es decir, la USB que booteaste para instalar ubuntu.

Dentro del **Live USB** seleccionas TRY UBUNTU o simplemente cancelas la instalación y cuando te abra el sistema operativo de muestra en la USB abres el Gparted (creo que ya viene instalado por default y si no pues **sudo apt-get install gparted**), y listo ahora si puedes redimensionar tu disco duro Raíz. :)

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esto. Alomejor no te deja particionar porque el disco este fragmentado y esto hay veces que proboca errores al particionar. Con este comando desfragmentaras tu unidad. Aunque si tu unidad es SSD no tiene ese problema y sera otro el problema que causa eso.

```
sudo e4defrag /dev/sda*
```

Comment: Sigue igual con el mismo problema...